# mvn clean package error ubuntu maven2

Tags: jar, maven-2

When I run mvn clean package on ubuntu (maven version 2) I get an error saying 9 jars are missing and they seem to be missing from the repository too. How can I resolve this issue?

`1) com.sleepycat:sleepycat_je:jar:2.1.30

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sleepycat -DartifactId=sleepycat_je -Dversion=2.1.30 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sleepycat -DartifactId=sleepycat_je -Dversion=2.1.30 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.sleepycat:sleepycat_je:jar:2.1.30

2) net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=net.sf.json-lib -DartifactId=json-lib -Dversion=2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.sf.json-lib -DartifactId=json-lib -Dversion=2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4

3) com.gf.eacore:eacore:jar:1.0

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.gf.eacore -DartifactId=eacore -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.gf.eacore -DartifactId=eacore -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.gf.eacore:eacore:jar:1.0

4) org.apache.commons:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.commons -DartifactId=commons-httpclient -Dversion=3.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.commons -DartifactId=commons-httpclient -Dversion=3.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.apache.commons:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1

5) com.jargs:jargs:jar:1.0

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.jargs -DartifactId=jargs -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.jargs -DartifactId=jargs -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.jargs:jargs:jar:1.0

6) com.jts:jtsclient:jar:9.60

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.jts -DartifactId=jtsclient -Dversion=9.60 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.jts -DartifactId=jtsclient -Dversion=9.60 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.jts:jtsclient:jar:9.60

7) org.logicalcobwebs:proxool:jar:0.9.1

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.logicalcobwebs -DartifactId=proxool -Dversion=0.9.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.logicalcobwebs -DartifactId=proxool -Dversion=0.9.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.logicalcobwebs:proxool:jar:0.9.1

8) com.tictactec:ta-lib:jar:0.4.0

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tictactec -DartifactId=ta-lib -Dversion=0.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.tictactec -DartifactId=ta-lib -Dversion=0.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.tictactec:ta-lib:jar:0.4.0

9) com.gf.utility:sekritUtility:jar:1.0

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.gf.utility -DartifactId=sekritUtility -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.gf.utility -DartifactId=sekritUtility -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
        1) edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.gf.utility:sekritUtility:jar:1.0

---

9 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  edu.mit.evodesign.bp:bp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`

Answer (score 0):

The *SNAPSHOT jars are jars being hosted on a private repo. 
Refer to [install third party jars](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)